# Black & Scholes Diffusion Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $ F:[0, T] \times [0, \infty) \to  \mathbb{R}^2 $  satisfies the Black-Scholes equation:

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t, x)
+ \frac{\sigma^2 x^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}
+ r x \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} - rF(t,x) = 0 
$$

for $t(x,y) \in  (0,T) \times(0,\infty)$, and subject to the following conditions:

$$\begin{cases} 
F(t,0) = 0 \text{ and }  \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F(t,x)}{x} = 1  & \text{for all } t \in [0,T]
\\F(T,x) = \max(x-k, 0) &\forall x \geq 0    
\end{cases}$$

Could result in:

$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 y} + \left( \frac{2r}{\sigma^2} -1 \right)\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} - \frac{2r}{\sigma^2}v
$$

just changing the variables:

$$\begin{align*}
            x &= Ke^y  \\
            t &= T - \left(\frac{2\tau}{\sigma^2}\right)
            \\F(t(\tau), x(y)) &= Kv(\tau, y)
\end{align*}$$

for $y \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $ \tau \in \left(0, \frac{\sigma^2 T}{2} \right)$, with $ v $ satisfying $ v(0,y) = \max(e^y-1, 0)$.

How could that be possible??

In addition if we set $ v $ differently, for example, being a function of another function $ u $:
$v(\tau, y) = e^{(\alpha y + \beta\tau)}u(\tau, y) $ as $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ transform the equation $ (2) $ into the diffusion problem:

\begin{cases}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 y^2}  &\text{on }   \left(0, \frac{\sigma^2T}{2}\right) \times \mathbb{R}
    \\ \\
    u(0, y) = \exp{(\frac{r}{\sigma^2} - 1)}\cdot \max(e^y-1, 0), &\forall y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}

How could we substitute in a proper way?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I made some changes to the math typesetting; see  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for some more tips.  In particular: for set membership use `\in` not `\epsilon`, for Cartesian product use `\times` not `x`, for the set of reals use `\mathbb{R}` not `\Re`.

Comment: Thank you very much!